# Will Cordova Android start supporting the current SDK version?

Tags: android, cordova

With Google's news that they will hide apps that target 2-year-old SDK versions, will Cordova start supporting the current SDK version to help apps get ahead of this requirement?

https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/04/google-will-soon-hide-neglected-apps-in-the-play-store/

Also, what would the timeline be for supporting targeting new SDK versions?

Comment: It already does, you can set the target SDK in config

Comment: Cordova only supports API level 30 so far.  https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/

Comment: API 31 support is right around the corner https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/1410